# Hide Search Bar Controller Manually

Tags: ios, swift

How do I hide the search bar controller manually when it is in the navigation bar in iOS 11? I have tried a few things but they don't work. I have included an image of the search bar I have setup. I want it to go back to being the normal navigation controller it generally is before I pull down to show the search bar. It seems like a single line of code that I am missing but I for some reason just cannot find that line of code. I want this to happen on view did appear so anytime a user comes back to this screen, the search bar is hidden. How do I do that?

Before 
[image]

As I am scrolling up 
[image]

Comment: Not sure about this.. did you try reloading content in viewDidAppear ?

Comment: Yes that doesn’t work either

Comment: I see. Can you share relevant code to get a more clear picture?

Comment: Did you try this: searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true

Answer (score 1):

Swift

To hide the searchBar use

```
navigationItem.searchController = nil
```

To show again the searchBar use

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

where `searchController` is the `UISearchController` of your controller

Comment: I don’t want to make it nil I just want to hide it so that when the user scrolls down again it shows like it normally does

Comment: Then use `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
searchController.active = false
```

or **swift 4+**

```
searchController.isActive = false
```

Comment: That didn't work. It was the first thing I tried. But it does not actually scroll the view up to hide the search bar. I even tried setting the content offset of the tableview and that didn't work.

Comment: Try using - navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true